# Error when trying to unpack axes from plt.subplots()

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a iris dataset and I'm trying to plot a distribution plot for all 4 columns of iris dataset :

```
df.columns    
['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)',
           'petal width (cm)']
```

I want to plot distribution of values I tried.

```
fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4)= plt.subplots(2,2)
sns.distplot(a = df.iloc[:,0])
```

I get a ValueError:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-265-58940645d27a> in <module>()
----> 1 fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4)= plt.subplots(2,2)
      2 sns.distplot(a = df.iloc[:,0])

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`plt.subplots(2,2)` [returns a 2x2 array](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots). If you want to unpack it, you need to provide the correct shape:

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2)
```